# Testing goodness of fit of data and function

Tags: statistics

I have a data set which I obtained from experiment e.g.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{x} & \text{y} \\ 
\hline
\\1 & 1.01 
\\2 & 3.99 
\\3 & 8.86 
\\4 & 16.02 
\end{array}$$

etc. I would like to statistically test if this experimental data fits with a theoretical function including random fluctuation

e.g. $y=2^x$

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think   $y=2^x$ might be   a better  model?

Comment: @copper.hat: no not really; see $x=3$.

Comment: @rlgordonma: You are right...

Comment: $y=x^2$ is a far better fit

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the mean squared error:
$$
  \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (y_k - 2^x_k)^2}{n}}
$$
this gives a measure of the distance of the points from the curve $y=x^{2}$

Comment: But how would you use the mean squared error to show that the data fits with a 5% significance or something like that?

Comment: You cannot, if you don't fix which is the expected variance of your variable.

Comment: Do you mean I need to specify if my error is Gaussian or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you can assess your experimental errors and model them as a normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$ (a dangerous assumption), you can use the [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).  For each data point $(x_i,y_i)$ you calculate the $y_{mi}$ the model predicts.  Then sum up $\frac {(y_i-y_{mi})^2}{\sigma^2}$.  You expect it to be about the number of data points less the number of parameters in your fit.

Comparing your data to fits $x^2$ and $2^x$ gives

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{x} & \text{y} & \text {2^x} & \text {2^x error}&\text {x^2}&\text {x^2 error}\\ 
\hline
\\1 & 1.01 &2 &0.99 & 1 & 0.01
\\2 & 3.99 &4 & -0.01 & 4 & -0.01
\\3 & 8.86 &8 & -0.86 & 9 & 0.14
\\4 & 16.02 &16 & 0.02 & 16 & 0.02
\end{array}$$

If we think our experimental error is $\pm 0.1$, the $\chi^2$ of $x^2$ is $\frac {0.01^2+(-0.01)^2+0.14^2+0.02^2}{0.1^2}=\frac {0.0202}{0.01}=2.02$